# set SurfaceView's margin programmatically

Tags: android, layout, surfaceview

I am adding the "SurfaceView" for camera in my layout xml file as,

```
<SurfaceView
        android:id="@+id/preview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="95dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"/>
```

But I want to set the **marginTop** dynamically. If I want to set the **SurfaceView's** **marginTop** programmatically, How can I do this?

I have searched in the internet. But I didn't get any answer. So anyone help me to do this.

Comment: http://sampleprogramz.com/android/surfaceview.php static & Dynamic surfaceview example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might do something like:

```
int margin = getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.surface_view_margin);
LayoutParams lp = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
lp.setMargins(margin, 0, 0, 0);
surfaceView.setLayoutParams(lp);
```

Does this help?

Comment: I'm using setLayoutParams but it gets overridden after onCreate etc. Do you know why? Please read my question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28304276/android-relativelayout-margin-works-but-gets-overridden